# Trying to Determine Lines of Code (LOC) using Atlassian FishEye

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

I want to determine lines of code (LOC) in a subversion repository.  Specifically, I want to determine how many lines of code my team supports in production (which is synonymous with our trunk).  I've heard mostly good things about Atlassian's FishEye tool so I downloaded a version and started crawling the repository to capture data.  As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlfPE.jpg), the LOC metric is not available and there is an error message which states, "This plugin does not have access to all the repository data for ESM/. Some data is not available: The repository may be indexing, may not support LOC or has "Store Diff Info" turned off."

I've confirmed the Store Diff Info option is selected for the repository based on the information provided [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Configuring+repository+details).  Is there a way to determine if our repository supports LOC or what might specifically be the problem?

Thank in advance,
Brandon

Comment: hmmm... i see LOC in all of my svn repos indexed by fisheye.  what version is your svn server? what version are your repositories? not that I think it matters - kinda grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

Fisheye supports LoC for Subversion repositories in general, but it collects that data only for trunk; check that commits to trunk are actually being recognized as such -- since Subversion does not require you to use /trunk as trunk, Fisheye's default [symbolic rules](https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/eAbSEQ) may not work.